# knockout add binding to dynamic form element

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

[image]

i got this form , all this input is integer . intpu B, C in a nested form by nested_form gem , when click add another , a clone of b,c （but different ids,names） will be added to the form .

C'value = A'value * B'value / 100

input A bindto underwriting_fee
input B bindto allocation_percent
input C ko.computed = A * B /100

```
var appmodel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.underwriting_fee = ko.observable();
    self.lines = ko.observableArray([new line(self.underwriting_fee)]);
    self.addLine = function() { 
      self.lines.push(new line(self.underwriting_fee));
  };
};

var line = function(underwriting_fee){
    var self = this;
    self.underwriting_fee = underwriting_fee;
    self.allocation_percent = ko.observable();

    self.fee = ko.computed(function() {
      //console.log(self.underwriting_fee());
      //console.log(self.allocation_percent());

      if(!isNaN(self.underwriting_fee()) && !isNaN(self.allocation_percent())){
         return self.underwriting_fee() * self.allocation_percent() / 100 ;
      }
    });
};
ko.applyBindings(new appmodel());
```

currently , when i click add another , there will two lines of b1-c1, one line by knockout ko oberservable array , one line by rails nested_form gem . and line by nested form doest work(input c not computed) , i did'nt want the line by knockout because of same id and same name .

i've read the documentation and googled a lot , but din't find a solution .

maybe i shouldn't use knockoutjs here ?

Comment: Could you show the relevant html?

Comment: @Arjan the html gen is too complicated